# What is the best way to handle a script with 40+ variables in Ruby 2.1.0

Tags: ruby

I just inherited a script that predefines 40+ variables as defaults followed by an OptionParser function in Ruby 2.1.0.

Short of a config file, is there a better way to handle this?

I have seen some other gems that seem to solve this problem, however I am trying to keep things to the std/core libraries so I don't have to make my entire organization install another gem if I can avoid it.

Also, if a config file is the way to go, any detail about this would be appreciated.

Comment: What data types are these variables?

Comment: We have entire systems that are built in Ruby, and make extensive use of YAML configuration files. We went with YAML because we can access the data in other languages, making it possible to keep apps outside the system using the same paths and settings. It has worked extremely well.

Comment: Types are strings and booleans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well either use a hash instead of variables, or use a YAML config file, or write a simple DSL, something like

```
class Options
  def self.parse
    obj = new
    yield(obj)
    obj.options
  end

  attr_reader :options
  def initialize
    @options = {}
  end

  def set(name, default = nil)
    @options[name] = default
    parse_option(name)
  end

  def parse_option(name)
    # code to parse the option
    # if option present
    #   @options[name] = value
    # end
  end
end

Options.parse do |o|
  o.set :name, "John"
  o.set :age, 15
end
# => { name: "John", age: 15 } or parsed values...
```

Answer (score 1):

A script that needs to predefine 40 variables with defaults may be doing too much - especially if your first instinct upon "inheriting" it is to refactor it.

I respect the urge to stick to the std/core libraries. Maybe what you should do here is think about the Unix philosophy of *Do one thing and do it well*, and find a way to break the script into smaller scripts, each with a single, better-defined purpose.

Comment: Agreed. I suspect it most likely started with 5 variables, and incremented gradually.